# ADF null value on combobox with partial trigger attribute

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I'm using adf as my interface, I have problems getting value on my 3 combobox it always gives me null value. I have 3 combobox the 1st combobx contain country and once the user select a value on 1st combobox(I use valuechangelistener/ I think is is synanymous to onlick) the 2nd combox is populated by the cities of the user selected country(I use partial trigger to refresh the 2nd combobox and I already set the 1st combobx to autosubmit true), And once the user select a value on the 2nd combobox(or city) the 3rd combobox should be populated by the street of the users selected city. However it seems like everytime the valuechangelistener on the 2nd combobox trigger it get's null value. Is this adf bugs or I have an error on my code.

To make everything clear
this is my jsf page
1st combobx(Country)

```
<af:selectOneChoice label=" " unselectedLabel="---Select Country---" autoSubmit="true"
                                    valueChangeListener="#{addDistrict.SearchRegion}" id="soc1">
                                        <af:forEach items="#{addDistrict.countries}" var="Country">
                                            <af:selectItem value="#{Country.id}" label="#{Country.countryNm}(#{Country.countryCd})" id="si1"/>
                                        </af:forEach>
                                    </af:selectOneChoice>
```

2nd combobox(City)

```
<af:selectOneChoice label=" " id="soc2" partialTriggers="soc1"
                                     valueChangeListener="#{addDistrict.SearchCity}" autoSubmit="true">
                                        <af:forEach items="#{addDistrict.regions}" var="Region">
                                            <af:selectItem value="#{Region.id}" label="#{Region.regionNm}(#{Region.regionCd})" id="si2"/>
                                        </af:forEach>
                                    </af:selectOneChoice>
```

3rd combobox(Street)

```
<af:selectOneChoice label=" " id="soc3" partialTriggers="soc2" autoSubmit="true">
                                        <af:forEach items="#{addDistrict.cities}" var="City">
                                            <af:selectItem value="#{City.id}" label="#{City.cityNm}(#{City.cityCd})" id="si3"/>
                                        </af:forEach>
                                    </af:selectOneChoice>
```

Is there any way I can get the value of the selected item of the 2bd combobox using valuechangelistener? I need the value of the 2nd combobox for me to query and populate the 3rd combobxbox.

As for the bean. 
I put this on @postconstruct to populate the combobox once the page load.

```
        calState = (OracleCallableStatement)con.prepareCall("{ call select_all_country(?) }");
    calState.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    calState.execute();
    rs = (ResultSet)calState.getObject(1);
    while(rs.next()){
        countries.add(new GetCountry(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3)));
    }
    calState.close();
```

And the valuechangelistener method

```
    public void SearchRegion(ValueChangeEvent e)throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    Connect conn = new Connect();
    con = conn.getConnection();
    calState = (OracleCallableStatement)con.prepareCall("{ call select_all_region(?, ?) }");
    calState.setObject(1, e.getNewValue());
    calState.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    calState.execute();
    rs = (ResultSet)calState.getObject(2);
    while(rs.next()){
        regions.add(new GetRegion(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3)));
    }
    calState.close();
    con = conn.closedConnection();
}
```

Anyway I use simple jdbc I don't want to use hibernate, JDBC is much faster and not time consuming when querying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this http://adf4beginners.blogspot.be/2012/11/cascading-select-one-choice-using-bean.html . I think it suits your use case.

Comment: sori for late reply :) thnx it was perfect. it is working now